# How can I add new columns using another dataframe (related to string columns) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Confusing title, let me explain. I have 2 dataframes like this:

dataframe named `df1`: Looks like this (with million of rows in original):

```
id `  text                             c1      
1     Hello world how are you people    1 
2     Hello people I am fine  people    1
3     Good Morning people               -1
4     Good Evening                      -1
```

Dataframe named `df2` looks like this:

```
Word      count         Points         Percentage

hello        2             2              100
world        1             1              100
how          1             1              100
are          1             1              100
you          1             1              100
people       3             1              33.33
I            1             1              100
am           1             1              100
fine         1             1              100
Good         2             -2            -100
Morning      1             -1            -100
Evening      1             -1            -100
                -1
```

`df2` columns explaination:

`count` means the total number of times that word appeared in `df1`

`points` is points given to each word by some kind of algorithm

`percentage` = points/count*100

Now, I want to add 40 new columns in `df1`, according to the point & percentage. They will look like this:

`perc_-90_2`   `perc_-80_2`  `perc_-70_2`  `perc_-60_2`  `perc_-50_2`  `perc_-40_2`  `perc_-20_2`  `perc_-10_2`   `perc_0_2`   `perc_10_2`  `perc_20_2`  `perc_30_2`  `perc_40_2`  `perc_50_2`  `perc_60_2`  `perc_70_2`  `perc_80_2`  `perc_90_2`

`perc_-90_1`   `perc_-80_1`  `perc_-70_1`  `perc_-60_1`  `perc_-50_1`  `perc_-40_1`  `perc_-20_1`  `perc_-10_1`   `perc_0_1`   `perc_10_1`  `perc_20_1`  `perc_30_1`  `perc_40_1`  `perc_50_1`  `perc_60_`  `perc_70_1`  `perc_80_1`  `perc_90_1`

Let me break it down. The column name contain 3 parts:

1.) `perc` just a string, means nothing

2.) Numbers from range -90 to +90. For example, Here -90 means, the percentage is -90 in `df2`. Now for example, If a word has percentage value in range 81-90, then there will be a value of `1` in that row, and column named `prec_-80_xx`. The `xx` is the third part.

3.) The third part is the count. Here I want two type of counts. `1` and `2`. As the example given in point 2, If the word count is in range of 0 to 1, then the value will be `1` in `prec_-80_1` column. If the word count is 2 or more, then the value will be `1` in `prec_-80_2` column.

I hope it is not very on confusing.

Comment: What is filled in new columns? 0 and 1 ? Also for `33.33` is value `perc_30_2` ?

Comment: Yes, 0 and 1. Yes the value `33.33` will be in `perc_30_2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#change previous answer with add id for matching
df2 = (df.drop_duplicates(['id','Word'])
         .groupby('Word', sort=False)
         .agg({'c1':['sum','size'], 'id':'first'})
         )
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'c1sum':'Points','c1size':'Totalcount','idfirst':'id'})

df2['Percentage'] = df2['Points'] / df2['Totalcount'] * 100


s1 = df2['Percentage'].div(10).astype(int).mul(10).astype(str)
s2 = np.where(df2['Totalcount'] == 1, '1', '2')
#s2= np.where(df1['Totalcount'].isin([0,1]), '1', '2')
#create colum by join
df2['new'] = 'perc_' + s1 + '_' +s2

#create indicator DataFrame
df3 = pd.get_dummies(df2[['id','new']].drop_duplicates().set_index('id'), 
                     prefix='', 
                     prefix_sep='').max(level=0)
print (df3)

#reindex for add missing columns
c = 'perc_' + pd.Series(np.arange(-100, 110, 10).astype(str)) + '_'
cols = (c + '1').append(c + '2')
#join to original df1
df = df1.join(df3.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0), on='id')
```

---

```
print (df)
   id                            text  c1  perc_-100_1  perc_-90_1  \
0   1  Hello world how are you people   1            0           0   
1   2   Hello people I am fine people   1            0           0   
2   3             Good Morning people  -1            1           0   
3   4                    Good Evening  -1            1           0   

   perc_-80_1  perc_-70_1  perc_-60_1  perc_-50_1  perc_-40_1  ...  perc_10_2  \
0           0           0           0           0           0  ...          0   
1           0           0           0           0           0  ...          0   
2           0           0           0           0           0  ...          0   
3           0           0           0           0           0  ...          0   

   perc_20_2  perc_30_2  perc_40_2  perc_50_2  perc_60_2  perc_70_2  \
0          0          1          0          0          0          0   
1          0          0          0          0          0          0   
2          0          0          0          0          0          0   
3          0          0          0          0          0          0   

   perc_80_2  perc_90_2  perc_100_2  
0          0          0           1  
1          0          0           0  
2          0          0           0  
3          0          0           0  

[4 rows x 45 columns]
```